# Call touchesEnded only if no touches on view

Tags: touch, sprite-kit

Currently, if I tap with two fingers on my screen and remove one of them but keep pressing with the other finger, the `touchesEnded`-method will get called.

But I want that the method only does something if there are no more touches in the view.

How can I check within the `touchesEnded`-method if there are still touches on the scene?

Answer (score 0):

The `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` methods get called each time for each touch that occurs on the screen. Each touch on the screen is associated with a `UITouch` object. You can find all touches that are associated with the event in the `(NSSet*) touches` object that is a parameter for these methods.

You need to keep track of the original touch using a global variable.

In your gameScene's implementation:

```
@implementation GameScene
{
    UITouch* currentTouch; //This variable will keep track of the touch.
}
```

Now, in the touchesBegan method:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        if (currentTouch == nil) {
            currentTouch = touch;

            //Handle touch code here, not outside.

        }
    }
}
```

And in the touchesEnded method:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        if ([touch isEqual:currentTouch]) {
            //This is the tracked touch, handle touch ending here.

            currentTouch = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code should help you handle touch for a single touch object.

For a better understanding, you can read up on the Apple's touch handling guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html).

Comment: keep a variable `touchNum` in `touchesBegan:` loop thru touches and add to touchNum. In `touchesEnded:` and `touchesCancelled:` loop the touches and subtract from touchNum.